# such element exception for no obvious reason

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have got the following piece of code and it keeps giving me errors. This particular error is  "such element exception". I put a hasNext() check to ensure this doesn't happen but i still get the error. The error also refers to the line containing  String kind = sc.next();

```
public static Meter load(Scanner sc) {
      MeterNumber meterNumber = MeterNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());

      while (sc.hasNext()) {
      int n = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      Tariff[] tariffs = new Tariff[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         String kind = sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         if (kind.equals("P")) {
            tariffs[i] = PeakTariff.PEAK_TARIFF;
         } else if (kind.equals("O")) {
            tariffs[i] = OffPeakTariff.OFF_PEAK_TARIFF;
         } 
      }

      return new Meter(meterNumber, tariffs);

      }
      return null;
   }
```

I have a main method through which i am trying to call the above method.

```
public class Testt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new java.io.File("Readings.txt"));

        Meter.load(sc1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    }       
}
```

This is the kind of input i have :

```
937 216 316 3 O 1041.1
531 481 889 2 P 788.5
```

Error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Meter.load(Meter.java:29)
    at Testt.main(Testt.java:19)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of exception? At which line?

Comment: @Dmytro I have edited an included error

Comment: Your file format doesn't match you code. For one thing, your code calls `sc.nextLine` constantly, but your file format does not have a new line after every number.

Comment: Scanner is not safe for multithreaded use. Do you have more than one thread reading? As you pass scanner to the method from outside it may be used in another thread as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT need to call `sc.nextLine();` to advance to the next line.

Instead, `sc.nextLine();` returns (and skips) the rest of the current line. You problably simply need to remove this call.

Advancing to the next line is done automatically by the `Scanner` when the end of a line is reached, because the `Scanner` knows that you are not interested in line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not so clear what exactly you are trying to do here, I suggest replacing

```
 while (sc.hasNext()) {
```

with

```
 while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner `kind = sc.next()` is unsafe. You have to check hasNext() first.